# What are reasons why a bountied question does not show up (not filterered by tags)

Tags: support, status-norepro, bounties, active-bounties

I have https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=bounties opened in a separate browser, so it should not be affected by tag-filtering.

This question does not show up. [X11 MIT-SHM performance of XShmPutImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69114935/x11-mit-shm-performance-of-xshmputimage)

Comment: It's the top bounties. I am not sure what the exact metric for that is, though. if you scroll to the bottom of the page it offers you to see the complete list. [You can find the question there on page 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=bounties&pagesize=50&page=6).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It shows up for me, on the 6th page of results (50 items per page).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=bounties  is not page'd (chromium) but it shows many (>100) bountied questions. You are right, I found what you mean by clicking "Questions" on the left side, then I can see that pages selection. It is very misleading to show many (>100) questions when these are just the top. Suggestion: at the bottom of the huge list show "more" and go to the page'd view.

Comment: @BerndElkemann There already is a link at the bottom of the list: "Looking for more questions with bounties? Browse the [complete list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Bounties)"

Comment: You are right, sorry I did not see that

Answer (score 2):

The default view on Stack Overflow is "Top Questions":

[image: default view on Stack Overflow]

This means not *all* questions, but rather the top, and the "Bountied" tab filters only those.

To see all questions with bounties, first go to the [Questions page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Bounties), and in there go to the Bountied tab:

[image: All questions page]

The question you mentioned is there, on [page 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=bounties&page=6) (when viewing 50 per page).